# Retrofit 2 - Correct response in HttpLoggingInterceptor but empty in response body

Tags: android, retrofit2

[Logcat Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cNn6.png)

Good Evening,

I'm using Retrofit2 to make a POST request using the following dependencies

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

Now the problem I'm facing is that the response with the **HttpLoggingInterceptor** is correct but **Response Body** is empty.

Here's my code

Retrofit2 Setup

```
 public Retrofit setUpRetrofit(){

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            .create();

    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build();

    return retrofit;
}
```

API

```
 @POST("hngeCommerceWebservice/rest/product/categoryNew/")
Call<Data> getData(@Body UserData userData);
```

MainActivity:

```
 Call<Data> dataCall = api.getData(userData);
    dataCall.enqueue(new Callback<Data>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Data> call, Response<Data> response) {
            int statusCode = response.code();
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString() + " STRING");
            Log.d(TAG, response.body().getSkuItems()+ " BODY");
            Log.d(TAG, response.raw() + " RAW");
            Log.d(TAG, response.message().toString());
            Log.w("Response ",new Gson().toJson(response));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Data> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage() + "");

        }
    });
```

This is the Response by                 **Log.w("Response ",new Gson().toJson(response));**

```
{"body":{"brandFilterdata":[],"priceFilterData":[],"skuItems":[],"validCouponCode":false},"rawResponse":{"body":{"contentLength":-1,"contentType":{"mediaType":"application/json","subtype":"json","type":"application"}},"code":200,"headers":{"namesAndValues":["Server","Apache-Coyote/1.1","Content-Type","application/json","Transfer-Encoding","chunked","Date","Thu, 15 Sep 2016 19:14:36 GMT"]},"message":"OK","networkResponse":{"code":200,"headers":{"namesAndValues":["Server","Apache-Coyote/1.1","Content-Type","application/json","Transfer-Encoding","chunked","Date","Thu, 15 Sep 2016 19:14:36 GMT"]},"message":"OK","protocol":"HTTP_1_1","receivedResponseAtMillis":1473966805216,"request":{"cacheControl":{"isPrivate":false,"isPublic":false,"maxAgeSeconds":-1,"maxStaleSeconds":-1,"minFreshSeconds":-1,"mustRevalidate":false,"noCache":false,"noStore":false,"noTransform":false,"onlyIfCached":false,"sMaxAgeSeconds":-1},"headers":{"namesAndValues":["Content-Type","application/json; charset\u003dUTF-8","Content-Length","235","Host","119.81.82.197:9090","Connection","Keep-Alive","Accept-Encoding","gzip","User-Agent","okhttp/3.3.1"]},"method":"POST","tag":{"headers":{"namesAndValues":[]},"method":"POST","url":{"host":"119.81.82.197","password":"","pathSegments":["hngeCommerceWebservice","rest","product","categoryNew",""],"port":9090,"scheme":"http","url":"http://119.81.82.197:9090/hngeCommerceWebservice/rest/product/categoryNew/","username":""}},"url":{"host":"119.81.82.197","password":"","pathSegments":["hngeCommerceWebservice","rest","product","categoryNew",""],"port":9090,"scheme":"http","url":"http://119.81.82.197:9090/hngeCommerceWebservice/rest/product/categoryNew/","username":""}},"sentRequestAtMillis":1473966804371},"protocol":"HTTP_1_1","receivedResponseAtMillis":1473966805216,"request":{"headers":{"namesAndValues":["Content-Type","application/json; charset\u003dUTF-8","Content-Length","235"]},"method":"POST","tag":{"headers":{"namesAndValues":[]},"method":"POST","url":{"host":"119.81.82.197","password":"","pathSegments":["hngeCommerceWebservice","rest","product","categoryNew",""],"port":9090,"scheme":"http","url":"http://119.81.82.197:9090/hngeCommerceWebservice/rest/product/categoryNew/","username":""}},"url":{"host":"119.81.82.197","password":"","pathSegments":["hngeCommerceWebservice","rest","product","categoryNew",""],"port":9090,"scheme":"http","url":"http://119.81.82.197:9090/hngeCommerceWebservice/rest/product/categoryNew/","username":""}},"sentRequestAtMillis":1473966804371}}
```

But Correct response with **HttpLoggingInterceptor**

Comment: What is the issue couldn't understand from above .